# Start Jenkins From .war file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have downloaded the Jenkins.war file in centos and I have also installed the java on it. Now I want to star the Jenkins server, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just run

```
java -jar Jenkins.war
```

on the command line.